# match column value, which is comma seperated column value

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 columns in a table name is **users**. In **zip_codes**, there are more than one zip codes with comma separation.

```
 id        ZIP_codes            user_email  

 1          123,785,333         a@gmail.com
 2          785,241,123          v@gmail.com
```

Now I have a other table name is **student**.

```
id        ZIP_code          std_email  

 1          123              std1@gmail.com
 2          241              std2@gmail.com
```

**student.zip_code** is coming from **first.php** and on **second.php**, it is matching with **users.zip_codes**. Now if **123** matches with other table then only a@gmail.com and v@gmail.com should be come and by 241 v@gmail.com should be come.

My code for **second.php** is:

```
 <?php
 extract($_POST);
"SET @search = '$zip_code'";
$SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM users where REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,)(', REPLACE(@search, ',', '|'), ')(,|$)')";

$result_set =  mysql_query($SQLSELECT) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
{
extract($row);
echo $user_email; 
}
            ?>
```

But it not working.

Comment: And no point are you running your `SET @search` line.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,)(', REPLACE(@search, ',', '|'), ')(,|$)')' at line 1

Comment: OR any other method to do this??

Comment: What does `"SET @search = '$zip_code'";` mean?

Comment: Why not just look for `LIKE CONCAT('%',@search,'%')`?

Comment: $SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM users where WHERE (',' + zip_codes + ',') LIKE '%,$zip1,%'";

Comment: BUT ERROR IS--  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (',' + zip_codes + ',') LIKE '%,345 ,%'' at line 1

Comment: You need a CONCAT before the parenthesis.

Comment: $SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE LIKE CONCAT('%',@search,'%')";

Comment: But error is same

Comment: Your line with `"SET @search = '$zip_code'"` does nothing. I guess you wanted to execute a query with this.

Comment: Your syntax is way off. `WHERE CONCAT(',', zip_codes, ',') LIKE '%,$zip1,%'"`

Comment: ok..then what I do? any option for my query?

Comment: First. you should do `mysql_query("SET @search = '$zip_code'");`

Comment: After that what to do?

Comment: Then do what @aynber says.

Comment: $SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE SET @search = '$zip_code' ";    But error is coming

Comment: Oy. I'd really suggest you read up on MySQL syntax. First query: `SET @search = '$zip_code'`. Make sure you actually run that query. Second query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(',', zip_codes, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', @search, ',%')`

Comment: I tried...But both query are not running.

Comment: Thanx to all for reply.....My query is solved

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE  FIND_IN_SET ($zip1, zip_codes)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my query by FIND_IN_SET ().

SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET ($zip1, zip_codes);